# What is the best way to set a flag based on results of subquery in Amazon Athena DB?

Tags: sql, subquery, presto, amazon-athena

I have a view based on a .csv in my s3 bucket, internal_user, which has all my internal user IDs. I want to set a flag, 0,1 to all users in my customerALL table with a single case statement. 
These did not work using the 'in' clause:

```
(CASE WHEN customer_id in (select customer_id from "internal_user")) THEN 1 else 0 END)
(CASE WHEN customer_id in (select array_agg(customer_id ) from internal_user) THEN 1 else 0 END)
```

Using the contains and array_agg from the Presto Array Functions, does work, but is very slow. I have 60K users and 2.5K are in the internal user table. It takes over 3min to run.

```
(CASE WHEN ((select contains((select (array_agg(customer_id ))from internal_user), customer_id) )) THEN 0 else 1 END)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: runs, but does not actually check anything.

(CASE WHEN customer_id in (select array_join(array_agg(customer_id ), ',' )from  internal_user) THEN 1 else 0 END)

Answer (score 0):

a join should be more efficient:

```
with db as (select distinct customer_id from internal_user)
select customerAll.customer_id, 
       case when db.customer_id is not null then 1 else 0 end 
from customerAll left join db on customerAll.customer_id=db.customer_id
```